# How to check in PHP if a variable is set and is_null

Tags: php, isset, isnull

This question is merely for information only.

I was wondering if there is a way to check if a variable is_set and if so check if it is set to null

Based on the [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) doesn't seems like that it is possible.

for example, let's say we have this code:

```
<?php
$x = null;
if(isset($x) && is_null($x)){
    echo '$x is set to NULL';
}else{
    echo '$x was never initialized';
}
echo "\n";
if(isset($y) && is_null($y)){
    echo '$y is set to NULL';
}else{
    echo '$y was never initialized';
}
echo "\n";
if(is_null($z)){
    echo '$z is set to NULL';
}else{
    echo '$z was never initialized';
}

?>
```

I would expect the page to show:

```
$x is set to NULL
$y was never initialized
$z is set to NULL   <it should give an E_NOTICE>
```

but I am getting

```
$x was never initialized
$y was never initialized
$z is set to NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$variablename_to_check_against = "varname";
$vars = get_defined_vars();
if (array_key_exists($variablename_to_check_against, $vars) && is_null($$variablename_to_check_against)) {
    echo "$variablename_to_check_against is NULL and exists";
}
```

`get_defined_vars` returns the local variable scope (inclusive the superglobals) in key-value pairs.

As `array_key_exists` returns also true when the variable is `NULL`, you can use it; then you only have to check if the variable is `NULL` with `is_null`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting correct result because when you assign

`$x = null;`

it means you're assigning a value to `$x` and that's why a condition

`if(isset($x) && is_null($x)){`

is set to `false` and that's control goes to `else` part

`isset($x)` returns `true` but `is_null($x)` returns `false` because value is set (whether it is `null`) and so `&&` returns false and control goes to `else` part.

In case of `$y`

`if(isset($y) && is_null($y)){`

`$y` is not declared. So `isset($y)` is `false` and therefore control goes to `else` part.

And why you got message about `$z` that `$z is set to NULL` because you didn't have check `isset($z)` and it's `null` by default and that's why `is_null($z)` condition becomes `true`.

Comment: I am assigning a value and that value is NULL, meaning `is_null($x)` should return true as well as `isset($x)` because the variable is SET and the value is NULL

Answer (score 0):

&& means both the conditions in IF clause must be true, as you can see in this [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

$x=null;
isset($x) returens false and is_null($x) returns true so we can see that else conditions executes